How is "Many Worlds" supposed to work?
Let's say Anne and Bob are spacelike separated and we carry out the usual entangled photons experiment. Each has a polarising analyser and the entangled photons are prepared in such a way that they are always anti-correlated, i.e. if Anne makes a vertical measurement and gets a positive result, Bob should get a negative result if he also makes a vertical measurement and vice versa. There are only two position on the analysers, vertical or horizontal. When a photon arrives at Anne's position she has a choice of what to measure, vertical (V) or horizontal (H). For the sake of argument let's say both happen according the MW interpretation. For either measurement she can get get either a positive (1) or negative (0) result. Again, let's also say both those possibilities happen. The same applies to Bob. To keep thing brief, let's say they only make one measurement each and check the correlation. The possible outcomes are:
01) Anne(V:1)   Bob(V:1)
02) Anne(V:1)   Bob(V:0)
03) Anne(V:1)   Bob(H:1)
04) Anne(V:1)   Bob(H:0)
05) Anne(V:0)   Bob(V:1)
06) Anne(V:0)   Bob(V:0)
07) Anne(V:0)   Bob(H:1)
08) Anne(V:0)   Bob(H:0)
09) Anne(H:1)   Bob(V:1)
10) Anne(H:1)   Bob(V:0)
11) Anne(H:1)   Bob(H:1)
12) Anne(H:1)   Bob(H:0)
13) Anne(H:0)   Bob(V:1)
14) Anne(H:0)   Bob(V:0)
15) Anne(H:0)   Bob(H:1)
16) Anne(H:0)   Bob(H:0)
(The bolded entries violate QM) These can be thought of as the potential world view that an individual 'sees' as there reality. The problem is some of these outcomes (1,6, 11 and 16) violate QM. How does the MW interpretation select which path the observer sees and more importantly, how does the MW algorithm make sure the observer never ends up in a QM violating branch?
It would seem MW would have to have prior non-local knowledge of the other observer's analyser position and result before branching. I don't see how the MWI overcomes the non local issue.
Edit: I am adding this even simpler version of the experiment, to make the issues even clearer, because I do not think any of the answers so far, really address the issues. In this version Anee always keeps her analyser vertical and Bob always keeps his analyser horizontal, so the correlation should be 100%. When photons arrive at Bob's analyser they can do one of two things, pass (1) or not pass (0), so using only local information the MW interpretation creates parallel worlds with both possibilities. After both have detected 100 photons they stop the experiment and Anne sends a message to Bob, stating her analyser was always vertical and also sends a list of the timestamps of when she detected photons. When Bob compares this list to his results he sees that there is only a 50% correlation, when QM predicted there should be 100% correlation. How does QM fix this issue? As I understand it The possible outcomes are like branches of a tree and while  we only see one branch, all branches still exist in parallel worlds. While Anne never changed the position of her analyser, there is a possibility that Anne might of changed her analyser position and in the tree of possible histories there is a world where Anne did change her analyser. At this point MW selects a branch where Anne did change her analyser position and in effect MW  changes the history and changes Anne's memory of the history. Even though Anne never changed the position, the fact that she might of is made a reality in the MW interpretation. In conclusion, MW changes the past to correspond wit the present. Answers that say the the explanation is that there is a superposition of all the possible branches with the branch we are in, do not explain how Bob receiving a 0 result becomes a 1 result as result of a superposition with the other potentially realizable results. At best this would result in a sort average of the result producing the incorrect 50% result.

An interaction of this kind suppresses interference between different
values of the measured observable: this effect is called decoherence:

This explanation is nearly the opposite of the previous. Some statements of the MW interpretation say the parallel worlds do not communicate and are in effect independent which makes me wonder what the purpose of the parallel worlds is. Decoherence is an expression of this independence and a break down on the connection. This still does not explain how if Bob ends up in a branch where he only gets 50% correlation when he should of got 100%. How does decoherence with the other worlds change his results to all 1's?

The many worlds interpretation (MWI) states that the equations of motion of quantum systems are an accurate description of how reality works.
A quantum system can be in a state $|\psi\rangle$ in which a measurable quantity $\hat{X}$ is unsharp. When you measure $\hat{X}$ a series of systems in that state you can get different values of $\hat{X}$ on different occasions. You can predict the probability of getting the different possible values of $\hat{X}$ given the state $|\psi\rangle$. For example, in a state
$$|\psi\rangle=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x_1\rangle+|x_2\rangle)$$
you have a probability of $1/2$ of getting each of the possible values $x_1,x_2$ when you measure $\hat{X}$.
A quantum system can undergo a process called quantum interference where an observable becomes unsharp and then sharp again in a way that depends on what happens to each of the possible states, see Section 2 of this paper for an example:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
Advocates of the MWI explain this by saying that the system really is in both states in this superposition and that interference is a process in which both of the possible outcomes interact to produce the result in a way that is described by the relevant equations of motion. Each system exists in multiple versions that can interfere in single particle interference experiments and in some other kinds of experiments such as Bell correlation experiments.
Where do the worlds come from? Suppose a system is interfering and it undergoes an interaction that produces a copyable record of some attribute of a physical system, such as a measurement. An interaction of this kind suppresses interference between different values of the measured observable: this effect is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
Since decoherence suppresses interference each version of the interfering system and the recording device evolve independently of the other versions. Over time this information spreads to other systems and so a collection of non-interfering versions of systems begins to form and to some approximation this looks a bit like a collection of parallel universes, hence the name of the MWI:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
You ask

How does the MW interpretation select which path the observer sees

If more than one outcome of a measurement is possible, then there is one version of the observer for each possible outcome. Some outcomes may be impossible and this occurs in Bell correlation experiments.

and more importantly, how does the MW algorithm make sure the observer never ends up in a QM violating branch?

How does the MWI explain Bell type correlation experiments? These experiments can be described using the Heisenberg picture in which the evolution of a physical quantity is described by evolving observables represented by Hermitian operators. When two systems become entangled the observables of each system have quantum information in their observables about the correlations between the observables, but this information can only be extracted by comparing measurement results from observables of both systems - this ic called locally inaccessible information:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223
What happens is that when Alice measures an observable of system 1 and Bob measures an observable of system 2 each of them separately differentiates into multiple versions: one for each possible outcome of the relevant measurement on their own system. The correlations are established  when the measurement results are compared as a result of the locally inaccessible information in each system. The branches that don't show the relevant correlations never exist. This is one of the ways in which the parallel universe approximation breaks down. Everett universes are established as a result of interactions between systems spreading records from one system to another and so before Alice and Bob have compared results their branching relative to another hasn't been established before such interactions:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328

Many worlds just says the same thing as the Schroedinger equation. Namely that the wavefunction, which tells you the probability of each outcome, never collapses. It says nothing about the wavefunction giving a non-zero result when you plug in impossible configurations. Assuming you prepared the Bell state perfectly, a wavefunction satisfying
\begin{equation}
\psi(1) = \psi(6) = \psi(11) = \psi(16) = 0
\end{equation}
will be the one appropriate to this type of experiment.

Would you agree that the wavefunction contains non local variables so that the MWI is as non-local as the Copenhagen interpretation? I find this answer very unsatisfying as it is very much in the "shut up and calculate" style. Basically I shouldn't ask what is physically happening.

If you mean that the wavefunction develops long range correlations as it evolves, that's definitely true. But the underlying Hamiltonian by which it evolves is local and so not subject to the usual problem with the Copehagen interpretation. You can ask for deeper physics behind Everett's proposal but no one knows what it is.

@KDP nah, MWI is local. It is one of its features.

@Anax Then you have to explain how MWI avoids this outcome 01) Anne(V:1) Bob(V:1) When Bob measures the vertical vertical polarisation , shortly after Anne has got a positive result for measuring the same orientation, his photon can be either V or H when only using local information. What in the MWI physically prevents Bob measuring V:1. Is that branch eliminated at a later stage by rewinding the history and replacing it retro-causally? The point of his question is about the proposed mechanism of MWI that avoids non locality. Can you explain that?

One way in which I've seen MWI often explained is that you can break down the evolution of a wavefunction of a particle into different paths that the particle takes. Each path represents a different possible branch, though two paths could end up meeting at the same location and thus when observed appear as a single branch of higher probability (in MWI, this probability is the probability of finding yourself to be in that specific branch). If you put together all of these paths, they will recreate the wavefunction.
In your example, the photon pair can be analysed as such: in each branch, when the two photons are emitted, they have been emitted such that the value to be measured must be opposite on the same axis (vertical or horizontal). Thus, we have the following branches:

Photon1: (V:1) (H:1) - Photon2: (V:0) (H:0)
Photon1: (V:0) (H:1) - Photon2: (V:1) (H:0)
Photon1: (V:0) (H:0) - Photon2: (V:1) (H:1)
Photon1: (V:1) (H:0) - Photon2: (V:0) (H:1)

We can express that briefly as $V0H0 + V0H1 + V1H0 + V1H1$ where we only note the values for photon1 for brevity (since we know that they'll always be opposite).
If Anne measures Photon1 and Bob measures Photon2 and each of them can chooise either V or H to measure, then we can see what happens for the first possible branch that can be followed ($V0H0$):
$VaVb(V0H0) + VaHb(V0H0) + HaVb(V0H0) + HaHb(V0H0) = A(V0)B(V1) + A(V0)B(H1) + A(H0)B(V1) + A(H0)B(H1)$
In the above $VaVb(V0H0)$ mean that Alice measured vertically, Bob measured vertically and photon1 was in state $V0H0$ (while photon2 was in state $V1H1$). $A(V0)B(V1)$ is used to describe that that A measured 0 vertically and B measured 1 vertically.
We can do the same for the other branches and we get:
$V0H1$ -> $VaVb(V0H1) + VaHb(V0H1) + HaVb(V0H1) + HaHb(V0H1) = A(V0)B(V1) + A(V0)B(H0) + A(H1)B(V1) + A(H1)B(H0)$
$V1H0$ -> $VaVb(V1H0) + VaHb(V1H0) + HaVb(V1H0) + HaHb(V1H0) = A(V1)B(V0) + A(V1)B(H1) + A(H0)B(V0) + A(H0)B(H1)$
$V1H1$ -> $VaVb(V1H1) + VaHb(V1H1) + HaVb(V1H1) + HaHb(V1H1) = A(V1)B(V0) + A(V1)B(H0) + A(H1)B(V0) + A(H1)B(H0)$
If we add all those together the final state that we get is $2A(V0)B(V1) + A(V0)B(H1) + A(H0)B(V1) + 2A(H0)B(H1)  + A(V0)B(H0) + A(H1)B(V1) + 2A(H1)B(H0) + 2A(V1)B(V0) + A(V1)B(H1) + A(H0)B(V0) + A(V1)B(H0) + A(H1)B(V0)$
You'll note that instead of getting outcomes like A(V0)B(V0), we get outcomes like A(V0)B(V1) twice. This is because the photons follow 4 paths each, in each path having a different vertical-horizontal combination. However, there are two paths in which the photon1 has V0 (and consequently photon2 has V1), therefore there are two paths that lead to an $A(V0)B(V1)$ outcome. On the other hand, outcomes in which Anne and Bob measure in different settings appear only once, because the two paths that have Photon1(V0) will differ in the Photon2(H) state (both H0 and H1 is possible).
The reason that the two photons cannot be measured to both have V0 is because they cannot be created to both have V0. The reason for that lies in how they were created. For your experiment to work, the setup is required such that they are created with this relationship. If it sounds very classical, it's because it is. Each singular branch behaves classically as far as I can tell. The quantumness comes from combining all the branches together.
The values of V and H for each photon in each branch are not hidden variables, btw, because hidden variables would imply that there is a variable that determines what specific value the photons will be measured in, but uniquely only once (in MWI all 16 outcomes happen, there is no hidden variable that selects one of the 16).
I probably could have written this answer a bit more formally, but I'm not a QM expert, just someone struggling to understand as well.

@GeorgosG +1 for being one of the few people to understand what my question is actually about and addressing the issue. When you said "The reason that the two photons cannot be measured to both have V0 is because they cannot be created to both have V0. " are you suggesting that the photons have a definite state before being measured? That would be quite a revelation!

@KDP Essentially, as far as I understand MWI (and I'm no expert, so I could be wrong) the photon is in a superposition of four states. That is not a definite state. Each of the four superposed states, however, is and as far as I can tell in MWI, the photon in a specific branch was always in that state, yes even before measurement. The analogue to collapse in this case is learning what branch of the superposition we are in and you can't learn that until the measurement happens.

It might also be relevant to note that before the measurement there has been no decoherence, so you can theoretically interact with all branches of the superposition (humans can't, because they are too big, but a particle could; or the photon may interfere with itself). Decoherence is usually used in MWI to explain why the branches can interact with each other at small scales, but at large scales/after a measurement has happened, it's no longer possible (practically).

I would like to reframe your question a little bit, instead of getting a measurement of 0, we would get a measurement -1, because this is an almost universally accepted convention.
We are measuring spin states on either the $x$ axis or the $z$ axis. We could label the spin operators of Anne $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z$ and that of Bob's $\tau_x$ and $\tau_z$. Their combined spin system is given by the singlet state, in the $z$ basis: -
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
For the second example where Anne's measurement returned $1$ and Bob's measurement returned $1$ too, there combined product state must collapse to the eigenvector of $\sigma_z \otimes \tau_z$ with an eigenvalue of $1$ inculding the fact the measurement on the state with the operators  $\sigma_z \otimes I$ and $I \otimes \tau_z$ must also return $1$. All these conditions mean that there is only one possible state for this which when expressed in the $z$ basis gives
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$$
The probability of this to occur is the "square" (the product of the inner product with its conjugate, to be more precise) of inner product of the singlet state and this state, which is equal to $0$, you can check the same for all the other states.
I don't exactly know about the "many world" interpretion, but I can assure that it must be that for each measurement, separate universes are produced in which the state of the particle depends upon their probability. So, because the probabilty of the specific measurements to occur given by you are $0$, no universe is actually produced with these measurements. Therefore there is no violation of quantum mechanics, it is just a paradox that arises from the "many worlds" interpretation.

No universes are produced. The set of many worlds is what it is and the thing changing with time is what value the wavefunction takes when each world is plugged in.
